# How to link Yii's Active Record model table with other table using JOIN

Tags: sql, join, activerecord, yii2

I am using Yii 2.

I have model `User` with table in DB.
I tried link this table with table `auth_assignment` which has columns `user_id`, `item_name` and `created_at` using `LEFT JOIN` clause. I wrote this:

```
$model = User::find()->leftJoin('auth_assignment AS a', '`a`.`user_id` = `user`.`id`');
```

Then I attach `$model` to `ActiveDataProvider`:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $model,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 5,
    ],
]);
```

But when I run application it prints only `User`s columns: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aseq6.png)

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `User` model you can't get attributes of another table(auth_assignment ).

You can do it by two ways.

1. Define relationship between `User` and  `auth_assignment` table in `User` model using `hasOne()`

Example : ( use your model name for auth_assignment table)

```
public function getAuth()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Authassignment::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

Than you can use `auth_assignment` table attributes as `$model->auth->user_id`;

2. Generate query **as array** as below, in this scenario you don't need to define relationship in model.

`$model = User::find()
  ->select('user.*,a*')
  ->leftJoin('auth_assignment AS a', 'a.user_id= user.id')
  ->asArray();`

`$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => $model,
'pagination' => [
   'pageSize' => 5,
],
]);`

Now you can use attributes as array variable i.e.
`$model['user_id']`  etc.

Comment: Thank you, Patel! `asArray()` works as it should for me.